# how to change label colors of charts in apache superset

Tags: apache-superset

i am trying to find a way to change the label colors for particular chart in apache superset. I am unable to get it working as mentioned in the documentation by adding label_colors to JSON Metadata of dashboard.

Comment: I've asked the same question with a bit more detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326962/where-are-label-colour-keys-stored-in-apache-superset

Comment: Hi. thanks for information. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: No I'm still trying to figure this one out

Comment: It seems functionality is still not implemented for this type of customisations.

Comment: I got it to work, see my answer to my post and let me know if that works for you

Comment: Hey thanks for the response.. i tried but was unable to get any results. i have moved to ELK to create the visualisations from superset. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can add like this with your column names in Edit Chart Metadata ---> Parameters

```
"label_colors":{
      "Girls":"#FF69B4",
      "Boys":"#ADD8E6"
}
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change color labels for an individual chart anymore, because the value has to be consistent for the rest of the dashboard, i.e. you will have to specify it on dashboard level.

To do that, have your dashboard on edit mode, press the 3 dots and choose Edit Properties. Look in the advanced option which contains JSON metadata, and add your labels as shown by [Sree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59926775/6447723) here.

```
"label_colors":{
  " Girls":"#FF69B4",
  "Boys":"#ADD8E6"
}
```

Checkout [Preset's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMC-WOgSBBg&t=85s) on that subject, second half shows how it's done now